# How to show the loading image before page_load event in asp.net 4?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I need to show the loading image until data fetched from the database and bind to the datagrid.I have a button  in the parent page (A.aspx), when we clicked on that button it will display the data in the Overlay (B.aspx). We have used greybox to display page in the overlay. I have placed the loading image in the B.aspx

The fetching and display the data in the datagrid are handled in the Page_Load. Since it all the logics are handled in the page_load, the elements will not be available in the DOM.

I am not able to show/hide the loading image.

Note: I have tried to placed the same loading image in the parent page (A.aspx). But  the loading image is displaying behind the overlay.

Please find the piece of code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           throbberSplashOverlay.Visible = true;
       }
}





#ctl00_CPSContentHolder_throbberSplashOverlay
{
    background-color:White;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 500;
}
#throbberSplash
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background:  url(../App_Themes/Blue/images/indicator.gif) no-repeat center center;
}



<div id="throbberSplashOverlay" runat="server" visible="false"><div id="throbberSplash"></div></div>
```

Comment: What's #ctl00_CPSContentHolder_throbberSplashOverlay?

Comment: are you redirecting to other page to display data?

Comment: @Ursus: throbberSplashOverlay.ClientID

Comment: @ThangamaniPalanisamy Are you sure the ID is correct? I think the correct way of handling the browser behaviour is setting `clientIDmode="static"`

Comment: @shreesha: Actually i am not redirect form A.aspx to B.aspx. I am just opening the B.aspx as modal

Answer (score -1):

as per my understanding you are displaying data in b.aspx.so use javascript function in b.aspx.onbeforeunload is for IE.
EDIT:while page is loading for the first time you can not call javascript function until the page loads completely.so show a wait image inside a div.and hide your entire page until the page loads completely.second time you can use onunload or onbeforeunload events.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>

</head>
<body onunload="doHourglass();" onbeforeunload="doHourglass();" onload="show();">
<div id="divWait" style="display:inline" >
      <h1>wait...</h1>
  </div>

<div id="main" style="display:none">
<input type="button" onClick="call your method" />
//your rest of the html
<div/>

<script>
function doHourglass()
{
console.log("inside dohour glass");
var divwait=document.getElementById('divWait');
 var divmainpage=document.getElementById('main');
 divmainpage.style.zIndex="0";
 divwait.style.zIndex="1";
 divwait.style.display='inline';
divmainpage.style.display='none';
}

function show()
{
console.log("inside show");
var divwait=document.getElementById('divWait');
 var divmainpage=document.getElementById('main');
 divmainpage.style.zIndex="1";
 divwait.style.zIndex="0";
 divwait.style.display='none';
divmainpage.style.display='inline';
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are opening b.aspx as modal or new window

Comment: as Modal  using Greybox

Comment: it is not working. it displaying the loading icon after the page completely loads successfully

Comment: what is happening?r u not able to see 'wait..' message?